# Photoswipe rotation issue when in ios4 UIWebView

Tags: uiwebview, ios4, rotation, photoswipe

I am using photoswipe 3.0.5 in my ios application. Everything is working correctly in the simulator (ios 6.1), but when i run the app on my real device (ios4.3) and i rotate from portrait to landscape and viceversa the uiwebview correctly rotates but the image doesn't.

It seems like a common issue, infact photoswipe's github page(https://github.com/codecomputerlove/PhotoSwipe) says:

`Work around for issue #141 now officially added - when rotating an app with PhotoSwipe displayed in a UIWebView, PhotoSwipe does not rotate. This seems to be an issue with UIWebView not PhotoSwipe. To enable this work around, set "enableUIWebViewRepositionTimeout = true" when creating your PhotoSwipe instance. You can also specify the frequency of this timeout by setting "uiWebViewResetPositionDelay" (default 500ms) - Please Note This is not needed for PhoneGap apps, nor web apps added to your homescreen.`

But i don't know where to add that line of code. Can anyone give me hand?

Would this 'work around' really do the trick? I'm asking this question because everything is working correctly on the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer. All you need to do is add 'enableUIWebViewRepositionTimeout: true' to the 'options' var:

```
    (function(window, PhotoSwipe){

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

            var
                options = {
                    enableUIWebViewRepositionTimeout: true,
                    preventHide: true,
                    getImageSource: function(obj){
                        return obj.url;
                    },
                    getImageCaption: function(obj){
                        return obj.caption;
                    }
                },
                instance = PhotoSwipe.attach( 
                    [
                        ...

                    ], 
                    options 
                );

                instance.show(0);

        }, false);


    }(window, window.Code.PhotoSwipe));
```